How to retrieve the name of the file from a GtkAda widget?
The attached code compile & runs.
-I should want to retrieve & manipulate the file name of a GtkAda widget.
I do see it's possible when we manage directly the object (How to create a file chooser with GtkAda?).
But i'm unable to do the same thing, meaning to get the file name of GtkFileChooserButton from inside the xml file.
-Do you can help & explain how you did because even using GnatStudio with its methods i don't see how to do, please.
Thank you Mark
-- window_callbacks.ads

with Gtkada.Builder; use Gtkada.Builder;

package Window_Callbacks is
  
  procedure On_File1_File_Set (Builder : access Gtkada_Builder_Record'Class);

end Window_Callbacks;



-- window_callbacks.adb

-- units from GtkAda
with Gtk.Main;

-- units from GtkAda
with Gtk.File_Chooser;           use Gtk.File_Chooser;
with Gtk.File_Chooser_Button;    use Gtk.File_Chooser_Button;

with Gtkada.File_Selection;      use Gtkada.File_Selection;


-- units from Glib
with Glib;              use Glib;
with Glib.Object;       use Glib.Object;

-- Ada predefined units
with Ada.Text_IO;       use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Exceptions;

package body Window_Callbacks  is

  ---------------------------------
  -- On_File1_File_Set  --
  ---------------------------------

  procedure On_File1_File_Set      (Builder : access Gtkada_Builder_Record'Class) is
                                                      
    Button : access Gtk_File_Chooser_Button_Record;

    begin
      null;
    --Button := Gtk.File_Button.Get_File_Name ( XXX, "file1"); --something like this..

     --Prints the file_name of the selection box.
    --Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("File selected " & Gtk.File_Chooser_Button.Get_File__Name (Button));

    end On_File1_File_Set;

end Window_Callbacks;



-- glade_8.adb

-- units from Gtk
with Gtk.Main;
with Glib.Error;     use Glib.Error;
with Gtk.Widget;     use Gtk.Widget;
with Gtk.Builder;    use Gtk.Builder;
with Gtkada.Builder; use Gtkada.Builder;

-- Ada predefined units
with Ada.Text_IO;       use Ada.Text_IO;

-- Application specific units
with Window_Callbacks; use Window_Callbacks;

procedure Glade_8 is

  Mon_Interface   : Constant String :=
    "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>"
  & "<!-- Generated with glade 3.40.0 -->"
  & "<interface>"
  & "  <requires lib=""gtk+"" version=""3.20""/>"
  & "  <object class=""GtkAdjustment"" id=""adjustment1"">"
  & "    <property name=""upper"">100</property>"
  & "    <property name=""step-increment"">1</property>"
  & "    <property name=""page-increment"">10</property>"
  & "  </object>"
  & "  <object class=""GtkListStore"" id=""liststore1"">"
  & "    <columns>"
  & "      <!-- column-name gchararray1 -->"
  & "      <column type=""gchararray""/>"
  & "    </columns>"
  & "    <data>"
  & "      <row>"
  & "        <col id=""0"" translatable=""yes"">test1</col>"
  & "      </row>"
  & "      <row>"
  & "        <col id=""0"" translatable=""yes"">test2</col>"
  & "      </row>"
  & "      <row>"
  & "        <col id=""0"" translatable=""yes"">test3</col>"
  & "      </row>"
  & "    </data>"
  & "  </object>"
  & "  <object class=""GtkWindow"" id=""window"">"
  & "    <property name=""can-focus"">False</property>"
  & "    <child>"
  & "      <object class=""GtkFixed"" id=""fixed1"">"
  & "        <property name=""visible"">True</property>"
  & "        <property name=""can-focus"">False</property>"
  & "        <child>"
  & "          <object class=""GtkFileChooserButton"" id=""file1"">"
  & "            <property name=""width-request"">196</property>"
  & "            <property name=""visible"">True</property>"
  & "            <property name=""can-focus"">False</property>"
  & "            <property name=""title"" translatable=""yes""/>"
  & "            <signal name=""file-set"" handler=""on_file1_file_set"" swapped=""no""/>"
  & "          </object>"
  & "          <packing>"
  & "            <property name=""x"">9</property>"
  & "            <property name=""y"">234</property>"
  & "          </packing>"
  & "        </child>"
  & "      </object>"
  & "    </child>"
  & "  </object>"
  & "</interface>";
  
  Builder       : Gtkada_Builder;
  Error         : aliased Glib.Error.GError;
  use type Glib.Guint;
     
  begin
    Gtk.Main.Init;

    -- Etape 1 : créer un Builder
    Gtk_New (Builder);
    
    if Add_From_String (Gtk_Builder(Builder), Mon_Interface, Error'Access) = 0 then
      Put_Line ("Error : " & Get_Message (Error));
      Error_Free (Error);
      return;
    end if;
   
    -- Etape 2 : créer les handlers des events
    Register_Handler (Builder, "on_file1_file_set", On_File1_File_Set'Access);

    -- Etape 3 : Do_Connect connecte tous les handlers enregistrés en une fois.
    Do_Connect (Builder);

    -- Etape 4 : Afficher la fenetre avec ses dépendances
    Show_All (Gtk_Widget (Get_Object (GTK_Builder (Builder), "window")));

    -- Etape 5 : Lancer la boucle infinie.
    Gtk.Main.Main;

    -- Etape 6 : Unref pour libérer la memoire associée au Builder.
    Unref (Builder);

  end Glade_8;
 


You need to get the Gtk_File_Chooser_Button, then get the filename from the button.  In window_callback.adb
 procedure On_File1_File_Set (Builder : access Gtkada_Builder_Record'Class) is
                                                      
    Button : access Gtk_File_Chooser_Button_Record;

 begin
    -- Get the file chooser button
    Button := Gtk_File_Chooser_Button(Get_Object(Builder, "file1"));

    -- Get the filename
    declare
       filename: string := Get_FileName(Button);
    begin
       Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("File selected " & filename);
    end;

 end On_File1_File_Set;

MISSING
A callback handler is also needed for the X button when you close the dialog otherwise it never closes and remains in the background.

Many thanks for the answer. I was halted with this problem.
